ionic capacitor push notifications not working for android and even device is not getting registered over azure hub
ionic capacitor push notifications not working for android and even device is not getting registered over azure hub but when i see over the ionic app console i can see device token and notification registered succesful logs from the ionic app
with recent changes Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) i have updated things according to it in azure hub as well but it is not working on android
ionic app console i can see device token and notification registered succesful logs from the ionic app
with recent changes Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) i have updated things according to it in azure hub as well but it is not working on android
Need a solution for it that what i need to change or do to get push notifications work on android capacitor app
